# Python csv.writerows() Writes to Many Columns on One Row and Not to Many Rows and One Column as Desired/Expected

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

The issue and question is:  Why does `csv.writerows()` output to many columns on one row only instead of multiple rows and one column as desired and expected?

Here are the details:

I need to gather lots of e-mails from various web site pages, and I don't have the time to COPY/PASTE each e-mail.

So I have developed an HTML web page e-mail scraper using a few standard libraries in Python as well as the third-party library Beautiful Soup 4.

The script(s) that I developed connects to a web page or in this case:  a file that is local on my computer.

The script works fine to scrape and gather all the HTML anchor tags (`<a></a>`) from an HTML file, and then compiles them into a list of anchor tags.

It then extracts the e-mail addresses with Regular Expressions, and then makes the two instances of each e-mail address (that are found in the anchor tags) all lowercase so that I can combine these into a set of unique e-mail addresses.

Then I convert this set of unique e-mail addresses into a list of e-mail addresses, and then alphabetize them with the `sort()` method of Python list objects.

I then convert this Alphabetic List of e-mails into a Tuple of Alphabetic e-mails.

I then append this Tuple of Alphabetic e-mails to a List containing exactly one item (i.e. so that the writing to CSV file does not separate each e-mail string into multiple columns as discovered in testing).

Then I write this List containing the Tuple to the CSV file, but the `writerows()` method writes them to one row only with multiple columns.

I want to write each e-mail address string to multiple rows in only one column.

Thanks for the help.

```
## IMPORT MODULES
## IMPORT MODULES
## IMPORT MODULES

import urllib
import bs4
import re
import pprint
import csv


## DECLARE VARIABLES
## DECLARE VARIABLES
## DECLARE VARIABLES

## EMPTY LIST FOR SCRAPED E-MAILS
ListOfEmails = []

# EMPTY SET FOR SCRAPED E-MAILS 
SetOfEmails = set()

## HEADERS FOR OUTPUT TO CSV FILE
##headers = ['emails'] 

## ROWS FOR E-MAILS FOR OUTPUT TO CSV FILE
ListWithOneTuple = []


## BEGIN MAIN PROGRAM
## BEGIN MAIN PROGRAM
## BEGIN MAIN PROGRAM

## OPEN LOCAL HTML FILE; READ THE HTML DOCUMENT
file = urllib.request.urlopen("file:///c://Python372/local_venv/index.html")
##print(file)
##print(type(file))
##print("\n")

## PARSE THE HTML; MAKE BEAUTIFUL SOUP
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(file, features="html.parser")
##print(soup)
##print(type(soup))
##print("\n")

## FIND ALL <a> ANCHOR TAGS; MAKE LIST OF ANCHOR TAGS
ListOfAnchors = soup.find_all("a")
##pprint.pprint(ListOfAnchors)
##print("\n")
##print("Number of Anchor Tags = ", len(ListOfAnchors))
##print("\n")

## FOR EACH ELEMENT IN LIST OF ANCHORS...
for each in ListOfAnchors:
    ##print(each)

    ## CONVERT EACH BEAUTIFUL SOUP OBJECT INTO STRING
    each = str(each)
    ##print(type(each))

    ## REGEX TO EXTRACT E-MAILS TO LIST
    ListOfMatches = re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", each)     
    ##print("ListOfMatches = ", type(ListOfMatches))

    ## FOR EACH ELEMENT IN LIST, MAKE E-MAILS LOWERCASE
    for email in ListOfMatches:

        ## CONVERT E-MAILS TO LOWERCASE
        EmailLowercase = email.lower()
        ##print(EmailLowercase, type(EmailLowercase))
        ##print("\n")

        ## APPEND E-MAILS TO LIST OF E-MAILS
        ListOfEmails.append(EmailLowercase)

## TEST PRINT LIST OF E-MAILS
##print("\n")    
##print("ListOfEmails = ", ListOfEmails)
##print(type(ListOfEmails), len(ListOfEmails))

## CONVERT LIST OF E-MAILS TO SET OF E-MAILS
SetOfEmails = set(ListOfEmails)

## TEST PRINT SET OF E-MAILS
##print("\n") 
##print("SetOfEmails = ", SetOfEmails)
##print(type(SetOfEmails), len(SetOfEmails))

## CONVERT SET OF E-MAILS BACK TO LIST OF E-MAILS FOR NEXT STEP ALPHABETIC SORTING
ListOfEmailsAlphabetic = list(SetOfEmails)

## ALPHABETIZE LIST OF E-MAILS
ListOfEmailsAlphabetic.sort()

## TEST PRINT ALPHABETIC LIST OF E-MAILS
print("\n") 
print(ListOfEmailsAlphabetic, type(ListOfEmailsAlphabetic), len(ListOfEmailsAlphabetic))

## CONVERT ALPHABETIC LIST OF E-MAILS TO TUPLE OF ALPHABETIC E-MAILS    
TupleOfEmailsAlphabetic = tuple(ListOfEmailsAlphabetic)    
print(TupleOfEmailsAlphabetic, type(TupleOfEmailsAlphabetic), len(TupleOfEmailsAlphabetic))

## APPEND TUPLE OF ALPHABETIC E-MAILS TO LIST TO MAKE LIST OF ONE TUPLE ITEM
ListWithOneTuple.append(TupleOfEmailsAlphabetic)

## TEST PRINT ROWS FOR CSV OUTPUT
print("\n")
print(ListWithOneTuple, type(ListWithOneTuple), len(ListWithOneTuple)) 

## OPEN CSV FILE TO OUTPUT LIST OF E-MAILS
with open('CSVofEmails.csv','w', newline='') as CSVFile:
    FileCSV = csv.writer(CSVFile, delimiter=';')
    ##FileCSV.writerow(headers)
    FileCSV.writerows(ListWithOneTuple)



## END MAIN PROGRAM
## END MAIN PROGRAM
## END MAIN PROGRAM

## GAME OVER
## GAME OVER
## GAME OVER
```

Comment: The `newline=''` is already empty.  It's not working.  I removed it now to test your suggestion, but it is not solving the issue.  The list of e-mails still prints to multiple columns in one row only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

Can you change the last piece of code like this.

```
content = [[i] for i in ListWithOneTuple[0]]

# OPEN CSV FILE TO OUTPUT LIST OF E-MAILS
with open('CSVofEmails.csv', 'w', newline='') as CSVFile:
    FileCSV = csv.writer(CSVFile, delimiter=';')
    # FileCSV.writerow(headers)
    FileCSV.writerows(content)
```

This works. CSV.writerows, actually accepts lists like this [[column, column], [column, column]], where the outer list is row and inner one is columns.

Comment: The `newline=''` is already empty.  It's not working.  I removed it now to test your suggestion, but it is not solving the issue.  The list of e-mails still prints to multiple columns in one row only.

Comment: @JerusalemProgrammer Can you try with newline='\n'?

Comment: Per your suggestion, I just tried `newline='\n'`, but this also produces the same results of all e-mails printed to many columns on one row.

Comment: @JerusalemProgrammer Can you write the list directly like this `FileCSV.writerows(ListOfEmailsAlphabetic)`? You are converting that list to one tuple and then again to one list with that one tuple. I am unable to run and check since i dont have index.html.

Comment: I have already tried this, but tested again per your suggestion.  When I write the `ListOfEmailsAlphabetic` as output, it splits each of the e-mails strings to be one letter in each column - yet it does so in multiple rows.

Comment: If you would like to test this yourself, simply change the file path at the top of the code to a local folder that includes an HTML file for your testing.  Of course you will need some `<a></a>` anchor tags that include a few e-mail addresses in order to extract them, e.g. `<a href="info@jerusalemprogrammer.com">info@jerusalemprogrammer.com</a>`.

Comment: @JerusalemProgrammer Please try my last edit. It works for me.

Comment: Good job.  Yes, absolutely it does work for me too.  This is the solution, i.e. a List Comprehension.  Thank you very much.